# Using Gazebo headless mode in a GPU cluster

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, ros-foxy, gpu

I have a question about image rendering in headless mode in a cluste.

My task is I want to train a RL agent in the cluster. I use ROS2 and gazebo simulator. Since the algorithm needs to constantly interact with the environment it needs to run gazebo in headless mode. I will need the output from the simulator of RGB images and other information such a odometry for training. What is the best way to achieve this ?

What i have seen so far to run gazebo ros in headless mode i have to run on the gazebo server and not run the gazebo client.

I have access to a Jetson which also has no display like a cluster . So since it was bit of a similar setup like the cluster , i wanted to see if it would work on that before testing on the cluster . I tested by ssh into a NVIDIA Jetson which has a docker container of my code(also including ROS2 and gazebo) and trying to run in headless mode . But the gzserver keeps crashing without giving any specific error even in the debugger mode. It just say it crashes with the :error
"[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 6487, exit code -2, cmd 'gzserver".

But if I run it with the client it does not crash.

The docker container had no issue running gazebo when i testted it on a different Jetson which had a display . So I dont think it is a issue with docker. Im using docker because the cluster doesnt have ROS and gazebo . Also itll allow me to easily duplicate my env

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ros:foxy

USER root
RUN sudo apt update
RUN sudo apt install locales
RUN  locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RUN export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# RUN sudo apt install software-properties-common
# RUN sudo add-apt-repository universe

# RUN apt update && apt upgrade

# nvidia-container-runtime
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
    ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
    ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics



ARG UNAME=foxy_user
ARG WS_DIR=/home/$UNAME/foxy_ws
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
RUN groupadd -g $GID -o $UNAME
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -N -u $UID $UNAME && \
    adduser $UNAME sudo && \
    echo "$UNAME ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/$UNAME && \
    mkdir -p $WS_DIR/src &&\
    chown $UNAME:$GID -R $WS_DIR

USER $UNAME
WORKDIR $WS_DIR/src
WORKDIR $WS_DIR
WORKDIR /home/$UNAME
RUN mkdir src

CMD /bin/bash
```

my docker-compose

```
version: "2.0"
services:
    dfki_foxy:
        image: dfki:foxy
        volumes:
            - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
            - $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw
            - ./../src:/home/humble_user/src
        environment:
            - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
            - QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
            

        # runtime: nvidia
        
        devices:
            - /dev/dri:/dev/dri
        privileged: true
        tty: true
        network_mode: "host"
```